# Azure API Management Report API using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-api-management

I'm trying to execute APIM Report API using Powershell but it doesn't works.

Here's powershell code.

```
$gen_sas_code = @"
using System;   
using System.Text;   
using System.Globalization;   
using System.Security.Cryptography;   

public class Sas  
{   
public static void GenSas()   
{   
    var id = "integration";   
    var key = "myprimarykey";   
    var expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10);   
    using (var encoder = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)))   
    {   
        var dataToSign = id + "\n" + expiry.ToString("O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);   
        var hash = encoder.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSign));   
        var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);   
        var encodedToken = string.Format("SharedAccessSignature uid={0}&ex={1:o}&sn={2}", id, expiry, signature);   
        Console.WriteLine(encodedToken);   
    }   
}   
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $gen_sas_code -Language CSharp

$sas = [Sas]::GenSas()

$interval = "PT15M"
$start_time = "'2017-10-16T04:02:00'"
$end_time = "'2017-10-16T04:15:00'"
$report_url = "https://myapim.management.azure-api.net/reports/byTime?api-version=2017-03-01&interval=$interval&`$filter=timestamp+ge+datetime$start_time+and++timestamp+le+datetime$end_time"
$report_headers = @{ "Authorization" = "$sas" };

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $report_url -Headers $report_headers
```

I referred this document about report API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-report-entity#ReportByTime).

Here's error response.

*The remote server returned error: (401) Unzuthorized

```
Invoke-RestMethod : リモート サーバーがエラーを返しました: (401) 許可されていません*
発生場所 C:\sas.ps1:56 文字:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $report_url -Headers $report_headers
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod]、WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

So, I consider that the powershell code has some problems because I have already confirmed that the SAS which is generated by above code works correctly by executing Report API using curl command.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using this script to generate the token https://github.com/Azure/api-management-samples/blob/master/scripts/Get_AzureRmApiManagementManagementToken.ps1

Comment: Hi Samir, thanks for replying. I tried again using SAS which was generated using your code but it didn't work. There was same error :(

Comment: However, I cannot understand this situation. The SAS which was generated by my code* was valid using curl so why it did not work with powershell? *I did copy&paste it from this doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-authentication#ProgrammaticallyCreateToken)

Answer (score 0):

It's a slightly annoying issue, but it comes down to newline handling in Powershell, the `\n` in the `.net` sample is referring to a newline, so you have to use the native way PowerShell declares a newline with a backtick instead, so do this:

```
var dataToSign = id + "`n" + expiry.ToString("O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

... instead of:

```
    var dataToSign = id + "\n" + expiry.ToString("O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```